# Magento2 Getting Error: The invoice can't be saved at this time. Please try again later

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, invoice, invoice-pdf, create-invoice

**Steps to replicate the problem:**

1. Create Order by user
2. Press invoice by admin
3. Cannot Submit invoice

**Error:**

The invoice can't be saved at this time. Please try again later.

Can you please suggest how I can solve it?

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the error log?

Comment: [2024-01-24T08:18:13.113807+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Exception: Deprecated Functionality: Creation of dynamic property Atcreative\XcomApi\Observer\Adminhtml\OrderSaveAfter::$redirect is deprecated in /home/mytheme/webapps/mytheme/app/code/Atcreative/XcomApi/Observer/Adminhtml/OrderSaveAfter.php on line 18 in /home/mytheme/webapps/mytheme/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:62
Stack trace:

Comment: You should focus to resolve the exception first.

Comment: @SuSu Dev can you share me your code.?

Comment: As per your logged error, it seems like $redirect related lib/class is deprecated. Can you share the same file code or the $redirect related code/class?

Comment: @SuSuDev Please share your 'Atcreative\XcomApi\Observer\Adminhtml\OrderSaveAfter' file here. There seems to be an issue with the '$redirect' variable in this file.